# How to work with Java Servlet on a frontend template?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java Enterprise Edition and i am working on a online store which uses Java as a back end programming language.
How do i work with Java on HTML templates? How can i change template content with Java servet without affecting its style (design)?
For instance my template contains HTML and other frontend technologies. Like the code below, how do i change listed products with Java servet?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Listed products</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li> Coffee </li>
<li> Ginger</li>
<li> Potato</li>
<li> Radish</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll have to be much clearer if you want an answer. I can't understand what you're asking. Elaborate. Post example code.

Comment: i want to change storefront elements dynamically with Java code. For example how do i change
   <h1>products</h1>
   <ul>
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2 </li>
   </ul>

How do i change listed items with Java code?

Comment: In standard Java EE, you use JSPs to generate HTML from Java Beans store in request attributes by a servlet. Clarify the question by editing it. Not by posting code in comments. You can also remove the coderanch reference which is unnecessary.

Comment: Use JSP or HTML5+JS/JQuery(Ajax) or Angularjs to generate dynamic content at front end eg. send an ajax request to the Servlet to know the available content of <ul> and then create dynamic list using java script

Comment: Please  provide an exact scenario along with the servlet code ur using,only then will someone will be able to help you!